# Bidirectional shifting using multiplexers

Tags: verilog

Edit:Only by the screenshots(http://prntscr.com/lv3uqw http://prntscr.com/lv3yhf) and my code below you can still understand my goal here just incase you dont want to read the text.

I am trying to write a verilog code for a universal shift register. My original register was working properly(the one without the `LR_bar signal`). But on this one i have no idea how i can make this conection(mux with ff) happen http://prntscr.com/lv3uqw and http://prntscr.com/lv3yhf.I had a suggestion that the for loop should start from -1 but i still cant find a solution. I would also like to avoid the h signal if possible(maybe we also use the w there). So basicly when `LR_bar=1` i want the shift register to `shift left` and when `=0` to `shift right`.

Tip for the screenshot: ser in l_sh stands for serial input for left shifting

(Also found that on a Mano Morris 3rd edition(6th is more detailed) book (Computer Design Fundamentals) which is, to a point , a little close to what i want. But i want 2to1 multiplexers . But the 2 first screenshots is what i want to achieve.
http://prntscr.com/lvb5bt  http://prntscr.com/lvb65f )

I think i describe it well...can someone solve this?

## MY NEW CODE(below) AND TEST AFTER SOME VALUES......http://prntscr.com/lvhk63

## I TRIED TO MIMIC THAT(http://prntscr.com/lvgx31 http://prntscr.com/lvgxgw http://prntscr.com/lvgxkw) BUT ONLY FOR THE SERIAL INPUT PART(MSB,LSB). PLEASE TELL ME WHERE IM WRONG. THANKS

the output should be the state of the register

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
module lr_shreg_n(in, out, clk, rst, LR_bar);
parameter n=4;

input in, rst, clk, LR_bar;
output [n-1:0] out;
wire [n+1:0] w;
wire [n-1:0] mux_out;
genvar i;

assign w[0]=in;
assign w[n+1]=in;

generate
  for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
     begin             
    mux2to1 MUX(.in({w[i],w[i+2]}),.sel(LR_bar),.out(mux_out[i]));
    dff ff1(.d(mux_out[i]), .q(w[i+1]), .clk(clk), 
        .rst(rst)); 
     end
endgenerate

assign out=w[n:1];

endmodule
------------------------------------------------------------ 

JUST AN ATTEMPT NOTHING TO LOOK 
module lr_shreg_n(in, out, clk, rst, LR_bar);
parameter n=4;

input in, rst, clk, LR_bar;
output [n-1:0] out;
wire [n+1:0] w;
wire mux_out;
genvar i;

assign w[0]=in;
assign w[n+1]=in;

generate
  for(i=-1;i<n-1;i=i+1)
     begin             
    mux2to1 MUX(.in({w[i+1],w[3+i]}),.sel(LR_bar),.out(mux_out));
    dff ff1(.d(mux_out), .q(out[i+1]), .clk(clk), 
        .rst(rst)); 
     end
endgenerate


------------------------------------------------------------  
module dff (d, q, clk, rst); 

input d, clk, rst;  
output reg q;      

always @ (posedge clk) begin : dff_block   
    if (rst==1'b1)     
      q = 1'b0;     
    else       
      q = d;   
  end 

endmodule 

module mux2to1(in, sel, out) ;

input [1:0] in;
input sel;
output reg out;

always @(*) 
 case(sel)
  1'b0: out=in[0];
  1'b1: out=in[1];
 endcase

endmodule

module shreg_n(in, out, clk, rst);
parameter n=4;

input in, rst, clk;
output [n-1:0] out;
wire [n:0] w;
genvar i;

assign w[0]=in;

generate
  for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1)
    dff ff1(.d(w[i]), .q(w[i+1]), .clk(clk), 
        .rst(rst));
endgenerate

assign out=w[n:1];
//assign out=w[n];
endmodule
```

Comment: @Serge I saw the comment and i am telling you again , this is my first post about this , and the users post you linked to me isnt even close to what i describe.

Comment: I suggested you to look at the other question because pieces of you code are really cut-n-paste from the same bad source as the other one with the same names and mistakes. you multiply drive the wire `w`  and have incorrect use of blocking assignments, inefficient use of generate block. So, fix them first. After this, if you still have issues, add code for 'mux2one' as well. It makes no sense to talk about the rest since your code is so wrong in the first place.

Comment: @Serge Thats why i ask for help. I dont know how to add my signals there. I will add the code ,wait

Comment: @Serge I will also attach my original shift register code. Because mine works properly and has no blocking assignments in it...

Comment: According to my first to screenshots , the output of the multiplexer should be the input of the flip flip which i think can be done. But how can the output of the flip flop be the input of the multiplexer when we need the same signal ?

Comment: @Serge Can you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking assignments might work in your specific case. As a matter of clean coding style and preventing any issues in the future, always use `<=` for all output assignments in flops (and latches).

Now, let's see what you want to do:

```
 w = out; // to keep the immediate values and avoid ordering issues

 for left shift:  w[3] -> x, w[2] -> out[3], w[1] -> out[2], w[0] -> out[1] , in -> out[0]
 for right shift: w[0] -> x, w[1] -> out[0], w[2] -> out[1], w[3] -> out[2], in -> out[3]
```

so, with a mux, say for out[2]`i == 2`, you would need a mux which does this:

```
 - w[1] -
         -> out[2]
 - w[3] -

 mux2to1 (.in({out[i+1], out[i-1]}),  .sel(LR_sel), .out(out[i]));
```

you also need to take care of special cases [0] with left shift and [n-1] with the right shift. For simplicity,
you can use `if` statement in the generate block to handle it.

```
if (i == 0)
  mux2to1 MUX0(.in({in, w[1]}), .sel(LR_bar), .out(tmp[0]));
else if (i == n-1)
  mux2to1 MUXN(.in({w[n-2], in}), .sel(LR_bar), .out(tmp[n-1]));
```

.out(out[i]));
    else
       mux2to1 (.in({out[i-1], out[i+1]}),  .sel(LR_sel), .out(out[i]));

Basically it creates yet another mux for those special cases, so that you have more of them.

As for the flop, there are at least 2 ways to approach it. You can flop results before or after the mux.

for the flopping before the mux (which i assumed in the above explanation), you just do

```
always @(posedge clk)
   if (rst)
      w <= 4'b0;
   else
      w <= out;
```

to do it after the mux, you would need to switch `out` and `w` and then flop `w` into `out`.  You can do a bit-by-bit flop as you did, but it makes the program more crowded in my opinion. Also it causes verilog to generate multiple one-bit flops which might affect simulation performance.

Another approach for shift registers with the flop is to something like the following:

```
always @(posegde clk) begi
   if (rst)
      out <= 4'b0;
   else if (LR_bar) begin
       out <= {out[2:0], in}; 
   end
   else begin
       out <= {in, out[3:1]}; 
   end
end
```

The above simplifies the code significantly. BTW, you would have an issue if you use blocking assignments there.

**Edit 1**

I modified your code to a workable condition down here based on my comments. 
you need a register `w` to keep the shift register value. You need the `tmp` to connect the *mux* with the *flop*. `w` is the output of the flop.

```
module uni_shreg_n(in, out, clk, rst, LR_bar);
  parameter n=4;

  input in, rst, clk, LR_bar;
  output [n-1:0] out;

  reg [n-1:0] w; // keep the value of the register shift
  wire [n-1:0] tmp;
  genvar i; 

  mux2to1 MUX0(.in({in,w[1]}), .sel(LR_bar), .out(tmp[0]));
  mux2to1 MUXN(.in({w[n-2], in}), .sel(LR_bar), .out(tmp[n-1]));

  generate
  for(i=0;i<n;i=i+1) begin  
    if (i > 0 && i < n-1) begin: loop
      mux2to1 MUX(.in({w[i-1], w[i+1]}), .sel(LR_bar), .out(tmp[i]));
    end
    dff ff1(.d(tmp[i]), .q(w[i]), .clk(clk),  .rst(rst));
   end
   endgenerate

   assign out = w; 

endmodule
```

Comment: I want my register to be on structural level. But i think that mux part might give  a solution.... give me some time.

Comment: I will try to add some ternary operators on my mux (in the universal shift register code) and see if it works.

Comment: if only i could do something like that mux2to1 MUX(.in({w[i],w[n+1-i]}),.sel(LR_bar),.out(h));
                             dff ff1(.d(h), .q(w[i]?LR_bar:w[n+1-1]), .clk(clk), 
  .rst(rst));  but i cant simulate it because of the LR_bar and i dont want to change my flip flop

Comment: also it has a parameter n so i think that out[2]i == 2 example part might be just coincidence

Comment: I can edit my post, post an accurate in my opinion example in universal register i have from mano morris 6th edition and i can post what i already have done ,if u are online right now and if you want to finish it if you are willing to.

Comment: I cant simulate it

Comment: Also why do we need the `tmp` to be more bits than 1?Can something like my mux_out  work?And why does my `mux_out` never get a value?I have `w[0]` as input in the multiplexer to be the `in`(serial input) and whenever i choose `LR_bar 1`, i never get the `mux_out` to be the `in` . Its always red

Comment: SIR, CAN YOU TELL ME IF ITS WORKING NOW?I THINK IT DOES. MY MUX_OUT SIGNAL DIDNT GET THE VALUE OF W, UNTIL I MADE MUX_OUT A N BIT SIGNAL . THEN IT GOT VALUES. WHY?

Comment: yes, it does work. you need to create a test bench to simulate it.

Comment: yup it works as well.Thanks for your time and for helping me .Good ppl.